# Debug a Background Task

Tags: debugging, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I always have trouble setting up functional background tasks in Metro register using `BackgroundTaskRegistration`.

Worst of all, I don't know how can I debug such task!

any idea or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, at last found it [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj542416.aspx) on msdn.